# Sending android intents over the internet

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Is it possible to send an Intent over the internet. I mean, I create the intent in mobile A and send that intent to mobile B. A braodcast receiver should be especified?

Answer (score 2):

> I mean, I create the intent in mobile A and send that intent to mobile B.

There is nothing built into Android for that. You are welcome to convert an `Intent` into some string or binary representation and send it to another device yourself, though.

Comment: So, this intent that I convert to a string could be catch by a BraodCast receiver that I created to this specific intent when my app is no runnig?

Comment: @joaovitorbarbosatavares: It would depend on how you decided to get the "intent in mobile A" over "to mobile B". Some things, like Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), would be able to deliver a message to mobile B and start up your app if it did not already have a process running. However, that would be true whether the message sent via GCM was an `Intent` or was a URL to a recipe. And there are plenty of approaches for passing data from one device to another (e.g., via your Web server) that would not deliver those messages to a device except when requested by your app.

Comment: I want to use sip to communicated mobile A to mobile B, and this way send the intent to notify the application that a call arrived and start up the application.

Comment: You should read up on google cloud messaging, broadcastreceivers and intent services.

Comment: @joaovitorbarbosatavares: I have no idea if what you want is possible. I would start by trying to determine if you can send arbitrary strings over SIP and how your app would receive those via your chosen SIP API. Then, and only then, worry about passing `Intent` objects that way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. You have an idea how it works in android native sip ?

Comment: @joaovitorbarbosatavares: No, sorry.